# На картинку с классом .projects__img нужно наложить градиент, не могу сообразить в какой класс его прописать чтобы работало

Tags: css

На картинку с классом `.projects__img` нужно наложить градиент, не могу сообразить, в какой класс его прописать, чтобы работало. Изображение задано в html тегом img.
[image: код]

```
    .project__img {
width: 1150px;
height: 550px;
object-fit: cover;
border-radius: 30px;
background: linear-gradient(
  180deg,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 100%
);
}
```

Comment: Охх сейчас вам в панамку накидают за скриншот кода. Посмотрите в developer console перезаписывается ли градиент чем-то сверху. Т.к. класс должен подхватить.

Comment: ой да пусть накидывают :) я тут впервые. К сожалению ничего не перезаписывает, просто не накладывается градиент. Я и так и сяк его

Comment: А принципиально его накладывать на `img`? Можно на `div`, а там использовать `background-image` и градиент.